# How do I prefill some fields in a form with data from another form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I've got a Wordpress site with an inquiry form on its own page and it works fine just fine, but now the marketing people want us to put another form on the Homepage with just name and email address fields. When the user clicks "continue" (the submit button) the site needs to load the Inquiry Form page, with the Name and Email fields pre-filled using the data from the Homepage form.

I can't seem to find a relevant example here or elsewhere online that relates specifically to Wordpress.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer requires some HTML and JavaScript knowledge. If your WordPress theme allows you to add custom HTML and JS to your pages then this will work for you.

First of all, create your homepage form and set the action attribute to the path of your inquiry form page. I'm assuming it's `/inquiry`.

```html
  <!-- On the home page -->
  <form action="/inquiry">
    <input type="name" name="email">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>
```

When a user fills this form and hits submit it will load your inquiry page and place the homepage form data in the URL as URL parameters (`/inquiry?name=John&email=test%40domain.com`)

Because the data we want is in the URL, we can use JavaScript to extract it and populate the inquiry form. Make sure that the JavaScript is placed after the form on the page.

```html
  <!-- on the inquiry page -->
  <!-- form -->
  <form id="inquiry">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="text" name="phone">
    <button>submit</button>
  </form>

  <!-- custom javascript -->
  <script>
    // Get the query parameters
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const params = Object.fromEntries(urlSearchParams.entries())

    // Set the query parameters to the relevant form inputs
    if (params.name) {
      // ⭐️ Adjust this selector to select your name field
      document.querySelector('#inquiry [name="name"]').value = params.name 
    }
    if (params.email) {
      // ⭐️ Adjust this selector to select your email field
      document.querySelector('#inquiry [name="email"]').value = params.email 
    }
  </script>
```